# Given N sorted arrays, check that there are two arrays that contains at least two common elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

If you have N sorted arrays where possible elements are integers from 0~N-1, and elements in a single array are distinct, how do you check if there are at least two arrays such that at least two elements are common?

For example, if I have following arrays where N = 5:

```
A[0] = {0},
A[1] = {1, 3},
A[2] = {2},
A[3] = {1, 4},
A[4] = {1, 3}
```

then A[1] and A[4] both have 1 and 3 in common, and therefore the answer is true.

In other example where N is again 5:

```
A[0] = {0, 4},
A[1] = {1, 3},
A[2] = {1, 2, 4},
A[3] = {0, 3},
A[4] = {1}
```

No two arrays A[i], A[j] have at least two elements in common, therefore the answer is false.

It was part of an interview question, which I was only able to solve in O(n^3) time, by iterating through each combination of arrays(A[i], A[j]) and in each iteration I scan from 0 to N-1 to check there are two common elements.

The interviewer indicated that there is a faster solution, and kind of hinted that utilize sortedness of the arrays, but I wasn't able to come up with better solution even if I was thinking of this problem for last 24 hours.

What would be a faster algorithm than O(N^3) to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: When comparing two arrays, you only need to compare elements in the overlapping ranges.

Comment: @Barmar Isn't that still O(N^3)?

Comment: Should the algorithm only check for such arrays or also return there indeces? E.g in example one only return true or the pair(1,4)

Comment: Just return true or false, no need to check exact positions

Comment: wait wait wait. If N is as u declared and you didnt consider the sortedness of the arrays, checking `in each iteration I scan from 0 to N-1 to check there are two common elements.` wouldnt be itself O(n^2) , since you dont have a O(1) contains lookup? so your algorithm would be O(n^4) ?

Comment: @TerryStorm, iterating 2 sorted arrays to find 2 common elements can be done in O(N) using similar techniques used by H4kor

Comment: yes i know that ofc, but `The interviewer indicated that there is a faster solution, and kind of hinted that utilize sortedness of the arrays` let me to believe, that u didnt consider this obvious solution. So the interviewer maybe mistook your answer as a O(n^4) solution with a wrong calculation. Dunno, wasnt there, but wanted to check the obvious first,

Comment: Yeah I mean in that sense, I took into account the fact that arrays are sorted. But he constantly wanted something better than N^3, because I gave him bunch of alternative algorithms that all fall into N^3 category.

Comment: In both examples, there are input values of `0` and `N`, the latter being outside the range named. Do you have reason to think the interviewer would allow for bitsets of N bits, and consider their manipulation taking time O(1)?

Comment: @greybeard, at some point I was thinking about bit manipulation(after the interview), but inherently, it's still O(N^3) assuming number of bits N is not fixed under some constant.

Comment: In the first example, N=5 and according to the problem each of these 5 arrays should contain elements between [0,4], so why does A[3] contains 5?

Comment: @ShankhoneerChakrovarty My bad, Edited the question. It does not affect the answer to each problem though. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create graph with array vertices and number vertices (at most 2N vertices).
Connect every array vertice with its numbers.
If two arrays have a pair of common numbers, there is cycle with length=4 (B-1-C-2 at the picture)

[image]

Find [if such cycle exists](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16393/finding-a-cycle-of-fixed-length)
Both creating graph and searching cycle takes O(N^2)

Comment: Wow! Really tricky! How can somebody expect to come up with such a solution on the spot during the interview?!

Answer (score 1):

It's doable in O(n*m) with `n = number of elements` and `m = number of arrays`

```
pointers[m] // one pointer for every array starting at begin();
commons[m][m] = 0 // count commons for every array combination
while(any pointer != end() )
{
   find pointer with lowest value;
   if any other pointer has this value;
      common[x][y] ++; // increment the commons counter for the corresponding arrays
   increment chosen pointer;
}
where common[x][y] >= 2 -> arrays contain 2 or more common elements
```

The algorithm iterates over all arrays "at once" always continuing with the smallest element.
This element is compared to the smallest **not visited** elements of the other arrays.
If the element are equal a not is taken in the `commons` array to keep track of the number of common elements.

After every element was visited, you only have to look into the `common` matrix to see which arrays have more than two common elements.

EDIT: over read something in the question. Sorry

Comment: It only checks for one common elements between two arrays. My question was if 2 elements from array A[i] is identical to 2 elements from A[j] where i != j

Comment: that would be just checking if there are arrays which shares 1 common number!? but actually thats part of the answer, since you can store all already found pairs which shares one common element in a hashmap or something, and if this set already contains this exact pair, you are finished...

Comment: Since he specified that there are `N` arrays, this answer is `N^2`

Comment: @H4kor, your edited solution iterates N^2 on the while loop because there are at most N elements in each A[i], and I think checking all the other pointers with same value will also take N, which I think it's still O(N^3)

Comment: you should clarify what the input size is. i would suggest #Arrays = N and maxSize(Arrays) = M. To find the lowest pointer u can easily do it (after the first iteration) in O(1). Then u iterate through all arrays: O(N), and you do it N*M times... so in generall O(N^2*M)?

Comment: @YShin Yes with that definition it would be in N^3. Didn't think about that.

Comment: @TerryStorm I gave the "wrong" definition for n = #total element in all arrays. Thereby the loop itself is O(n). Finding the smallest pointer is in O(m) and the comparison too. Thereby the whole algorithm is in O(n*(2)m) = O(nm). BUT in YShin question N is the max. size of an array AND the number of arrays. => My algorithm O(N*N*N)

Comment: ahhh i misread the question myself... feeling stupid now... but isnt the actual input size is O(n^2)=O(m). so the question got a bit confusing, since the algorithm is actually O(m*root(m)) ?! (messured on the possible input size)